# Is it possible to deploy a solution to a web application so that its features are only visible within this web application?

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2010

I have a solution with several site/web scoped features (SP2010). Id like to deploy this solution to **one specific web application**. The features should only show up in the sites/webs which reside in this web application.

By adding *Safe Control Entries* to my solution I am able to deploy the solution to a specific web application. However, the features of my solution still show up in all other web applications.

There is a similar question on SO, see [Creating a solution that deploys to selected WebApplications but copies the assembly to GAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086460/creating-a-solution-that-deploys-to-selected-webapplications-but-copies-the-assem/4165281#4165281). From the answers given, it seems that it is not possible. However the TS himself states that it is actually working (for him).

**EDIT**
To make things clearer, my confusion is probably best summarized by the following question:

*Why is it possible to activate a feature on a web application where it has not been deployed to?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot control the visibility of web/site scoped features to single web application. They will be either visible in all of them or none.

My first question would be why do you want a restriction like this ? A feature should be reusable component which can be activated anywhere once deployed. Note that however, the activation needs Administrator previleges.

If you really want to restrict:
- Hide it and use powershell or stsadm script to deploy.

Comment: The fact that the feature shows up everywhere leads to the obscure situation that you are able to activate a feature on a web application where the feature is not deployed at all. Note that I deployed the solution only to ONE SPECIFIC web application. All the files and assemblies the feature depends on are only available on this web application. It simply does not make sense to give the end-user the possibility to activate a feature in a web application where it is NOT deployed at all. I guess I am missing sth?

Comment: No you are not missing anything. The thing is you are confusing between solution and feature. A solution can be deployed to particular web application. However, a feature is always deployed globally and then can be selectively activated on multiple web/site/web app/farm depending on scope. It is another thing that a solution can *also* contain feature in it, but this is just one of the cases.

Comment: I think thats a bad design decission. If you want to cleanly seperate sites for different clients, you can NOT do this by giving everyone an own web application, because client-specific features will also show up in EVERY OTHER web application. So the only possibility would be to give every client an own farm. Phew!

Comment: Since you are using SharePoint 2010, look at the sandboxed solutions... This is what exactly you are looking for in your situation....

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I allready looked at sandboxed solutions. They cannot be deployed at a web application level, only at site collection level. Furthermore SS have other restrictions we're not willing to accept.

Comment: Is above comment true that "A solution can be deployed to particular web application. However, a feature is always deployed globally and then can be selectively activated on multiple web/site/web app/farm depending on scope"; If so, then under what circumstances would a person deploy wsp to a web app (I beleive that the dll will go to that webapp's bin folder in this case), otherwise he could rather deploy globally (dlls would go to GAC in this case); Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to prevent users from enabling a feature in a web application, where you don't want them to, is to make all the site scoped features dependent on a web application scoped feature.

Answer (score 0):

This visibility is certainly a pain especially when you have a ton of site collections a huge variable user base.  Adding new things into the Features list for people to mess with can be problematic since it can cause more support headaches than it is worth.

If you really want to keep things from being exposed to others, you will most likely need to deploy these features as hidden features and then activate them from the command line for the people who need them.  I suppose you could also write your own Feature admin screen that would take into account the current web app.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sandbox Solution For this. Because Sandbox solutions are not stored in File System(Physical path) and assemblies can't be deployed to Global Assembly Cache(GAC).

Comment: The questions was "Is it possible to deploy a solution to a web application...". AFAIK, sandboxed solutions cannot be deployed to a web application.

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of links( I have already tested) which will provide you solution

http://sharepointempower.com/2013/01/deploying-solutions-to-a-specific-web-application-2/
http://aravindrises.blogspot.in/2013/03/deploy-sharepoint-solutions-at-web.html

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**