# Feature with WebApplication scope - deploy only to one webapplication

Tags: sharepoint

After deploying my new Sharepoint solution, containing a feature with WebApplication scope, I noticed that feature was added to ALL webapplications in the farm.

The solution was deployed to a one particluar webapplication, so I wonder if such behavior is correct. Any way to make feature appear only in WebApplication, solution was deployed to?

Answer (score 0):

How did you deploy from powershell or from central admin?  If you deployed from central admin you should have been given a list of web apps to deploy too, but if you did powershell and left off the WebApplication flag (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607534.aspx), it would have deployed to all of the web apps.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately by design.
The solution is deployed to a single web application, e.g.
[image]

but the features are visible on all web applications, i.e.:
[image]

Feature /= solution. That means that some elements from the solution (not features) will appear only in the designated web application.

One workaround is to hide the feature so that users cannot activate it.

Check out also these posts:
[Is it possible to deploy a solution to a web application so that its features are only visible within this web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679468/is-it-possible-to-deploy-a-solution-to-a-web-application-so-that-its-features-ar) 
[Creating a solution that deploys to selected WebApplications but copies the assembly to GAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086460/creating-a-solution-that-deploys-to-selected-webapplications-but-copies-the-asse?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score -1):

if the solution deployed to ABC webApp so it won't deployed to another WebApp, if it happened better remove from all WebApp and deploy to ABC webApp by PowerShell command.

-
Praveen